# Using a .json private key instead of p12

Tags: google-api, openssl, google-oauth, pkcs#12

This is a two part question, if that is OK here. I maintain an application that reads Google data, using a .p12 key file that is downloaded from Google by our customers. One customer for some reason can't make a .p12 file, but has a .json file containing a property called "private_key" that begins with "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" then has what looks like base64 encoded binary data.

I found this Stackoverflow question: [Is it possible to convert JSON private key into PKCS12 format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561790/is-it-possible-to-convert-json-private-key-into-pkcs12-format)

I tried to follow the instructions, making a text file that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAg...ctlG0=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(of course, with the full data in place of ...)

But when I execute the command: openssl -rsa -in jsonkey.key I get the error "Could not read private key".  Any idea what the problem is here?

Here is the second part of my question. Ideally I would prefer to convert the json key using my own code. In my original application code, basically what I am doing is opening the .p12 file and reading all the binary data into memory, then calling "d2i_PKCS12(&p12_cert, &pkdata2, flen)" where pkdata2 is a pointer to the p12 data.  Could I assume that the data from "private_key" could be decoded from base64, and it would be the equivalent to the .p12 binary data?

Comment: Update - I was able to get the conversion working - turns out there are embedded line feeds within the private key data that I had to account for. I'm still interested in doing the same thing in code, if anyone has any insight on that.